# how to return the number of cells for two different cells in uicollectionview programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, xcode9

I am currently working on a project where I have one CollectionViewController and multiple cells registered. I need assistance with returning the number of cells I want to be shown for the each cell.

For Example I have registered:

```
    collectionView?.register(PhotoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: picCell)

    collectionView?.register(ArticleCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: articleCell)
```

As you can see I have registered two cells. How can I return 7 photo cells and 4 article cells to be displayed in my collection view programmatically?

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}
```

As of right now I am only able to return 7 photo cells successfully.

Answer (score 1):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}   

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell //Default will never Execute  
    if data == photo (
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell
        return cell )
    else if data == article {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! articleCell
        return cell
    }
    return cell

    }
```

use this approach to determine the cell type . Here Your data if its audio than that cell weill be used and if its article than other cell will be used and  count return will be total data count.

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return 11 
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    if (indexPath.row < 7)
    {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: picCell, for: indexPath) as? PhotoCell
        {
            //your code here
            return cell
        }
    }

    else if (indexPath.row > 6)
    {

        //if indexing is needed create new index starting at 0
        let articeCellindex = indexPath.row - 7

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: articleCell, for: indexPath) as? ArticleCell
        {
            return cell
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }



}
```

Amey's answer is fine but they omitted how to structure your cell data in a way so that both cell types are contained in one structure. An alternative is to explicitly state which rows will display the cell data. Make sure both the picCell and articleCell reuse identifiers refer to the same cell.

Comment: Hey, how could I make the photo cell one size and the article cell another size? Would you be taking this same structure?